# Stress on Particles and Past Tense

Tags: ударение, tense, particles

I am never quite sure when to stress particles such as `не`.

Also, I am confused about people saying that the `a` in the past tense feminine is stressed, and whether or not this is always the case.

*I am aware that stress is very irregular and can move around when the case, gender, number, or conjugation changes.*

Comment: See also [Как правильно ставить ударение: "не дАл" или "нЕ дал"?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When **не** is written separately, I can only think of two cases when it's stressed:

- the past tense of **быть**, except the feminine form (so **нé был**, **нé было**, **нé были**, but **не былá**);
- the pronouns **некого** and **нечего** when split by a preposition: **нé у кого**, **нé с чем**.

The **-а** in the feminine past tense is *not* always stressed, and I'm sorry to say there's no useful rule to determine when it is (i.e. one that wouldn't have a ton of exceptions) other than a *tendency* for those verbs to have monosyllabic or **-ти** or **-чь** infinitives. (For our purposes, a monosyllabic infinitive with a prefix still counts as monosyllabic: **проспать**–**проспалá**, same as **спать**–**спалá**. Again, mostly. **Забыть** is an exception. It really is *very* irregular.)

Comment: `В тот миг, когда пучиной\\Был кубок поглощен,\\Пришла ему кончина,\\И больше не пил он.`

Comment: @Matt Or Tsoy's "кричат — нам нЕ дали петь, кричат — попробуй тут спой". I don't think those are useful for a learner to know; what's more, I think the later a learner encounters such one-off phenomena the better. With any unusual and curious things in a language you learn, there's always the danger of coming to think of them as more of "a thing" than they really are. To give a personal example, I wish I hadn't known about the Scots form "cannae" before I was aware of its context. I think I used it as a "hip" way of saying "can't" a couple of times, which was weird and random.

Comment: Also, just wondering, is 'но' pronounced as 'nah' or 'no'? Or does it depend on the situation?

Comment: It's always "no".

Answer (score 2):

Stress in past tense feminine verbs is a painful issue for many native speakers too.

Answer from [here](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/127410272828):

> В каких глаголах женского рода ударение падает на последний слог?
>   Ударение в прошедшем времени обычно падает на тот же слог, что и в неопределенной форме глагола (например, смотрЕть — смотрЕла). Однако у большинства односложных глаголов (и глаголов, образованных от односложных с помощью приставок) ударение в форме женского рода прошедшего времени падает на последний слог:
>   взялА
>   бралА
>   ждалА
>   лгалА
>   вралА
>   дралА
>   рвалА
>   звалА
>   гналА
>   лилА
>   пилА
>   далА
>   У этих глаголов со всеми приставками (кроме приставки вы-) и с постфиксом –сь ударение также падает на последний слог: убралА, совралА, взорвалАсь, отозвалАсь.
>   Исключения.
>   У глаголов класть, красть и красться, пасть, упасть, слать, послать, стлать ударение в форме женского рода прошедшего времени остаётся на основе:
>   клАла, крАла, пАла, упАла, крАлась, слАла, послАла, стлАла.

Comment: I found that one too. The exceptions list is too incomplete to present it as authoritative. Ела? Стригла? Выла?